# How to create multiple columns of based on averages of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to have columns that contain the averages of previous columns.
e.g. for the dataframe below:

```
        Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5 ...  ColN 
Row1     5     6     9     10    9   ...   10 
Row2     4     7     4     0     9   ...   8 
Row3     4     8     3     1     7   ...   5
```

I want to loop this so I create columns "Avg_2_4", "Avg_3_5", all the way to "Avg_N-2_N".

I can get the average for Col1 to Col3 by using the below code

```
col = df.loc[:,"Col1":"Col3"]
df["Avg_1_3"] = col.mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: `df.rolling(3, axis=1).mean()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the example given below will solve your problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cols = 4
rows = 10

# Sample Data Creation
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1,cols+1):
    df['Col'+str(i)] = np.random.randint(0,10,rows)

# Column wise rolling mean calculation with a window of 3    
avg = df.rolling(window=3, axis=1).mean()

# Assinging appropriate column names to calculated mean df's columns
avg_cols = pd.Series(range(1,cols+1)).astype(str)
avg_cols = 'Avg_' + avg_cols.shift(2) + '_' + avg_cols
avg.columns = avg_cols

# merging the results
df = pd.concat([df,avg.dropna(axis=1)], axis=1)
```